# Tomar datos de un input

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo un sistema de cronometro en cual estoy tratando de tomar los datos del input y llevarlos por `$_GET` para poder calacular tiempo por valor.

```js
var startTime = 0
var start = 0
var end = 0
var diff = 0
var timerID = 0
function chrono(){
 end = new Date()
 diff = end - start
 diff = new Date(diff)
 var msec = diff.getMilliseconds()
 var sec = diff.getSeconds()
 var min = diff.getMinutes()
 var hr = diff.getHours()-diff.getHours()
 if (min < 10){
  min = "0" + min
 }
 if (sec < 10){
  sec = "0" + sec
 }
 if(msec < 10){
  msec = "00" +msec
 } else if(msec < 100){
  msec = "0" +msec
 }
 var time = hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec + ":" + msec
 var inputTime = min + "." + sec
 document.getElementById("chronotime").innerHTML = time
 document.getElementById("chronoInput").value = inputTime
 timerID = setTimeout("chrono()", 10)
}

function chronoStart(){
 document.chronoForm.startstop.value = "Stop"
 document.chronoForm.startstop.onclick = chronoStop
 document.chronoForm.reset.onclick = chronoReset
 start = new Date()
 chrono()
}

function chronoContinue(){
 document.chronoForm.startstop.value = "Stop"
 document.chronoForm.startstop.onclick = chronoStop
 document.chronoForm.reset.onclick = chronoReset
 start = new Date()-diff
 start = new Date(start)
 chrono()
}

function chronoReset(){
 document.getElementById("chronotime").innerHTML = "0:00:00:000"
 start = new Date()
}

function chronoStopReset(){
 document.getElementById("chronotime").innerHTML = "0:00:00:000"
 document.chronoForm.startstop.onclick = chronoStart
}

function chronoStop(){
 document.chronoForm.startstop.value = "Start"
 document.chronoForm.startstop.onclick = chronoContinue
 document.chronoForm.reset.onclick = chronoStopReset
 clearTimeout(timerID)
}
```

```html
<span class="time" id="chronotime">0:00:00:000</span>
<form name="chronoForm">
<input class="btnStart" type="button" name="startstop" value="Start" onClick="chronoStart()">
<input class="btnReset" type="button" name="reset" value="Reset" onClick="chronoReset()">
</form>
<input class="ress" type="text" name="reported_time" value="" id="chronoInput" step="0.01" min="0.01" required readonly="readonly">
```

Debajo del input estoy tratando de tomar el valor del mismo asi:

```
<?php
$var = $_POST['reported_time'];
?>
<a href="calc.php?tiempo=<?=$var;?>">Calcular</a>
```

Pero en `calc.php` no me trae los datos del input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Además de que no me queda claro cómo estás enviando los datos a **calc.php**, veo dos problemas. Primero que estás intentando leer una variable de JS en el código de PHP. Segundo, que estás mezclando usando *$_POST* cuando en tu enunciado hablás de *GET*.
Teniendo todo ésto en cuenta, una solución podría ser modificar el form así :

```
        <span class="time" id="chronotime">0:00:00:000</span>
        <form name="chronoForm" action="calc.php" method="get">
            <input class="btnStart" type="button" name="startstop" value="Start" onClick="chronoStart()">
            <input class="btnReset" type="button" name="reset" value="Reset" onClick="chronoReset()">       
            <input class="ress" type="text" name="reported_time" value="" id="chronoInput" step="0.01" min="0.01" required readonly="readonly">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
```

y si hubiera un archivo calc.php, sería (lo básico) así:

```
<?php
   $tiempo = $_GET["reported_time"];
   echo "tiempo=".$tiempo;
?>
```

Espero sea de ayuda.

Saludos,

Comment: Veo que no estaba usando ni `acction` ni `method`, `<form name="chronoForm" action="calcular.php" method="get">`, me he olvidado de lo más simple, soy un fiasco. Muchas gracias @l-alejandro-m